# Generalizing Fibonacci-type sequences (performance)

Tags: performance, haskell, recursion, fibonacci

Today I found the Haskell Fibonacci definition of:

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Exploring, I wrote the "tribonacci" numbers as:

```
tribs = 0 : 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) (zipWith (+) tribs (tail tribs)) (drop 2 tribs)
```

This works fine, so I tried to generalize to any "fibonacci-type" sequence using the same basic idea:

```
nbonacci n   = (take n (repeat 0)) ++ [1] ++ (z n) 
   where z 1 = zipWith (+) (nbonacci n) (drop 1 (nbonacci n))
         z x = zipWith (+) (z (x-1)) (drop x (nbonacci n))
```

This works, too: it correctly gives the sequences I'm after. Unfortunately it's also horribly slow, many times slower even when generating the same fibonacci and tribonacci sequences. How can I express the same idea in a way that gets better performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [worker-wrapper transform](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Worker_wrapper):

```
nbonacci n = go where
    go = take n (repeat 0) ++ [1] ++ z n
    z 1 = zipWith (+) go (drop 1 go)
    z x = zipWith (+) (z (x-1)) (drop x go)
```

Comment: Whoa. Thanks! I'm not sure I completely understand why that works but I'll read the Wiki.

Comment: @BrianFearn This isn't really the worker-wrapper transform. What it does is giving a name `go` to the list which is *shared* between all the functions calling each other, avoiding recalculating it all the time. Your original had `nbonacci n` everywhere, which is a function application and the results of those are *not* shared by default.